# Mvc pick out 1 item from each category

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a list of objects with this class:

```
public class CategoryForHome
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Img { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Many of the objects have the same category but i am interested in creating a new list containing only 1 object/category. I cant figure out how this is done? 
With distinct()? With Take()?

```
Var newList = new List<CategoryForHome>()

Foreach(var item in list)
{
 //Do something
   newList.Add(item)
}
```

I hope im clear with what im trying to achieve, any help appreciated.
Tahnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in 
                list.GroupBy(catForHome => catForHome.Category)
                    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(catForHome => catForHome.Name).First()))
{
    // got item with the lowest name in every category
}
```